# Dash DB support for timestamp with time zone

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

I want to store timestamp with time zone in dashdb. I see that db2 supports data type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE for this purpose. But when I am trying to create table in dash db using this type, I am getting below error. Is this because dash db just doesn't support this type, even though db2 does. Or is there something I am doing wrong? Appreciate the help

> DDL failed with message 
>   _ Exception. _ state = 42601; error code = -104; error Message = Error for >batch element #1: An unexpected token "time" was found following "COL2" >timestamp with". Expected tokens may include: "REFERENCES".. _CODE=-104, >_STATE=42601, DRIVER=3.66.46

Comment: `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is only supported in DB2 for z/OS, at least for now. dashDB, which is based on the DB2 for LUW engine, does _not_ support this data type.